# Computation of integration wrt counting measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=(x^2+3)\chi_{[0,2]}(x)$. Then how do we compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\,d\mu$ where $\mu$ is counting measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\,d\mu = \int_0^2 f\,d\mu \geq 7\int_0^2 \,d\mu = 7\mu([0,2]) = +\infty.
$$

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^2...$?